# Add Facebook Send button

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the WooCommerce and the Slim Jetpack plugins together, where I would like to be able to socially connect my products to the customers.

I have the Facebook "Like", Google+ and Pinterest buttons for sharing purposes, but was wondering if there was a way to easily add a Facebook "Send" icon as well to the list?

[image]

On the Facebook developers page - [developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send) it can generate the code for a Send button.  However, when the scripts are placed into the website, it clips the the flyout box as seen in the last image.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to to integrate the Facebook Send button, style it to be inline with the others (as they are built using iframes) and avoid the clipping issues?

**Update:**  
To avoid the clipping - 
`.fb_iframe_widget > span {width: 450px !important;}`

Comment: what does the send icon do?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

Comment: the code builder is right there on the page

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "share"? While Facebook doesn't offer a widget for that anymore, you can hand code it.  http://cferdinandi.github.io/social-sharing/

Comment: The "[Send](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send)" feature.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> go setting->slim jetpack active Sharing option click on configure
> ```

```
manage which you display shareing icon using drag and drop which is 
manage in below image.
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't include the Facebook Send icon

Answer (score 0):

go for sharing free plugins like:-

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebookall by [sourceaddons](http://sourceaddons.com/)
you can easily edit plugin share code 
go to wp-content/plugins/facebookall/helpers/facebookall_share.php
and add facebook send button code in share function from:- [facebook](http://developers.facebook.com)